# Добавить один элемент к QuerySet в Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Нужно добавить один элемент в начало результирующего списка.

Пытаюсь так:

```
q = Book.objects.values_list('id', 'name')
q.insert(0, {'opt':'val'}) - AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Comment: Откровенно говоря не знаю для чего такой костыль нужен, но раз уж начали костылить, то могу предложить в Serializer которому передаются данные переопределить метод to_representation() и в нем руками засунуть нужный объект. Либо как вариант прямо viewSet перегнать полученный QuerySet в питоновский объект и добавить в него элемент руками. И то и другое не правильно, но...

Comment: @virvaldium с чего Вы взяли, что это дрф?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 ни с чего не взял. Просто пальцем в небо попытался угадать

Comment: это не DRF, а Django

Comment: Давайте начнем с вопроса, зачем?